# How to programmatically find the amount of compute units used in a transaction?

Tags: compute-budget, test-bpf

Title. Looking to do this from my bpf tests.

Comment: Just be aware that depending on how many bumps it takes you to generate PDA (if you are doing it), costs may differ quite a bit between invocations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[getTransaction](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction) JSON-RPC method returns an object with transaction metadata with `computeUnitsConsumed` field.

**Examples on how you can get the amount of compute units used in a transaction**

In JS:

```
const tx = await connection.getTransaction(<TX_HASH>);
console.log(tx.meta.computeUnitsConsumed);
```

In Rust:

```
const result = client.get_transaction(<TX_HASH>)?;
println!("{:?}", resut.transaction.meta.unwrap().compute_units_consumed);
```