# How compute unites and Lamports are interrelated

Tags: lamports, compute

How are the Lamports related to compute units?
For example, for one ED25529 signature verification, it costs 5000 lamports, so if we verify an ED25519 signature in a contract using: Program id: Ed25519SigVerify111111111111111111111111111 and Instructions: new_ed25519_instruction
How many compute units will it take, and what will be the transaction fee?

Comment: Does this help? https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/how-to-programmatically-find-the-amount-of-compute-units-used-in-a-transaction

Answer (score 1):

In a program you can log the compute units and calculate so what costs how much compute.

```
    sol_log_compute_units();
```

or you can use a macro like this:

```
/// Total extra compute units used per compute_fn! call 409 CU
    #[macro_export]
    macro_rules! compute_fn {
        ($msg:expr=> $($tt:tt)*) => {
            ::solana_program::msg!(concat!($msg, " {"));
            ::solana_program::log::sol_log_compute_units();
            let res = { $($tt)* };
            ::solana_program::log::sol_log_compute_units();
            ::solana_program::msg!(concat!(" } // ", $msg));
            res
        };
    }
```

The transaction cost does only change when you set priority fees like this:

```
  const computePriceIx = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
    microLamports: 1,
  });
```

otherwise every transaction signature will just cost 5000 lamports.

here are more infos on compute budget:

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/090e11210aa7222d8295610a6ccac4acda711bb9/program-runtime/src/compute_budget.rs#L26-L87